# C loops-OK to change counter or condition within loop?

Tags: c

Several books show me how to correctly write for, while, and do loops.
Lots of online articles compare them to each other.

But I haven't found any place that tells me what not to do. For example, would it screw things  up if I change the value of the counter or condition variable within the loop?

I would like an answer that is not machine dependent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can change the counter within a loop and it can sometimes be very useful.  For example in parsing command line arguments where there is an option flag followed by a value.  An example of this is shown below:

Enter the following command:

`program -f filename -o option -p another_option`

Code:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

 char *filename, *option, *another_option;

 if(argc > 1){
   for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
     if(strcmp(argv[i],"-f")==0){
        filename = argv[++i];
     } else if(strcmp(argv[i],"-o")==0){
       option = argv[++i];
     } else if(strcmp(argv[i],"-p")==0){
       another_option = argv[++i];
     } else {
       printf("Option \"%s\" not recognized, skipping\n",argv[i]);
       continue;
     }
   }
 } /* end if argc > 1 */

 return 0;
}
```

The example program automatically increments the counter to access the correct command line string. There are of course ways to incorporate counters etc., but they would only make the code more cumbersome in this case.

As others have pointed out, this is where many people write bugs and one must be careful when incrementing counters within loops, particularly when the loop is conditional upon the counter value.

Answer (score 7):

It is not invalid to change a loop counter inside a loop in C.

However, it is probably confusing to future readers and that's a good reason *not* to do it.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by "screw things up".

If you know what you are doing, you can change counter. The language has no restrictions on this.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the counter variable in the loop is allowed, but be careful to know what you are doing to not create infinite loops by decreasing the variable when you shouldn't be.

Some algorithms actually benefit from this, but of course if you do this it makes your code less readable so make sure you comment what you are doing also.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can change the counter and condition variables. They will just be evaluated with the next iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Definiteley you can.But be careful not to make the loop disorder. Alter a conter in the loop happens a lot in do...while and while.

```
do{
  counter++;
  some expressions;
}
while(counter < SOMEVALUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in C/C++/C# You can change the counter etc. in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Like many other techniques, as long as you know what do you do, it's fine.

For example, this code:

```
int i;
for (i=0;i<5;i++)
  printf("%d\n",i--);
```

is an infinity loop, but this version of bubble sort:

```
int *arr,n;
//allocate memory, assign values, and store the length of the array in n
int i;
for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)
  if (arr[i]>arr[i+1]) {
    int temp=arr[i];
    arr[i]=arr[i+1];
    arr[i+1]=temp;
    if (i) i-=2;
  }
```

is fine. (It's not exactly bubble sort. Instead of using nested loops, I go back in the array after swapping members in it)

Answer (score 1):

Be careful changing counter variable inside a loop, not all loops are the same, "while" loop behaves differently.  see this example?

No, it is *NOT* an infinite loop (on some compilers). run it, and see...

```
i=5;
while (i--)
{
    i=100;
    printf("%d \n",i)
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example compiler on which this is not an infinite loop? Tested with `gcc` and it was an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

We can change the counter value inside the loop but the final counter value wont be reflected as the for loop wont override the counter value.
here is the example in QTP VB script.

```
iLast = 4
For i= 1 to iLast
iLast=2    
Next
```

Here the for loop should execute only for 2 times as iLast value is updated to 2 inside the loop but it is executing for 4 times.